# How to read out the Parse.com object I have retrieved?

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform

I already manage to retrieve the object but I can't get the values I need. I use Angular JS and my setup looks like this:

HTML

```
<h1>{{myTrip[0].attributes.title}}</h1>
<br/>
<p>{{myTrip[0].attributes.descr}}</p>
```

JS:

```
var Trip = Parse.Object.extend("trip");
var query = new Parse.Query(Trip);
query.equalTo('user', currentUser.id);
query.find({
    success: function(result){
        $scope.myTrip=result;
        console.log(result);
        alert('success');
    },
    error: function(error){
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

The console log displays the following ('attributes' is a little lower but in the same hierarchical line as what you see below "0"):

[image]

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Cause in the browser nothing is showing up although the console log shows all the variables and attributes are there.

-Gerd

Answer (score 0):

According to [Parse.com documentation](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#objects-retrieving), `query.find` returns a list of objects in its `success` callback. To access each object's property you need to call `.get`:

```
var score = gameScore.get("score");
```

So, if I understand your Parse object schema correctly, it seems like you should do as follows:

```
<h1>{{myTrip[0].get("title")}}</h1>
<br/>
<p>{{myTrip[0].get("descr")}}</p>
```

Comment: Looking at [Parse documentation](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#objects-retrieving), it seems that you can only retrieve properties by using `.get`, like so `var score = gameScore.get("score");` Is `attributes` such property?

Comment: I actually have a working project with the find method. That is why I am wondering why it does not work now. I even filled up the db by hand to exactly recreate my old projects and it still does not work. See this link: https://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html

Comment: Like I said, you need to use `get` on the Parse.Object. Does it not work with `get`?

Comment: Nope! AsI have the console.log printing out the screentshot above it means it has already downloaded the necessary info in the objects. When I refer to it as result[0].attritbutes.title in console.log it works, when I do the same with $scope variable it does not. I tried simple simple binding to test if scope and controller are correct and it worked so the problem is not there, as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add $scope.$apply()

like so:

```
var Trip = Parse.Object.extend("trip");
var query = new Parse.Query(Trip);
query.equalTo('user', currentUser.id);
query.find({
success: function(result){
    $scope.myTrip=result;
    $scope.$apply();
    alert('success');
},
error: function(error){
    alert('error');
}
});
```

and now it works! I don't really get it but I thought I put it out here if someone has the same problem.

-Gerd